# how to insert date time object in the type of DateTime column in database using php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I want to insert a DateTime object in database where the column type is DateTime. How can I achieve this?

I am using this code:

```
 $cdate = new DateTime('now')
     $cd = $cdate->format('d/m/Y h:i:sa')
$udate = new DateTime('72 hours');
     $ud = $udate->format('d/m/Y h:i:sa')
          $insert = "insert into `winpc_user(mac_address,reg_date,updated_date,status,processor_name,ram_size,os_Name, os_Bits) values('$mac','$cdate','$udate','$stat','$proName','$rSize','$osName','$osBits')"
```

Comment: try `format('Y-m-d h:i:s')`

Comment: FYI: DATETIME's format is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same as the comment above, [`DATETIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)'s format is:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

Quite straightforward to follow using [`date()`'s](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) format function, it'll share the same with the `->format()`:

```
->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Sidenote: Of course, this needs to be quoted as well on insertion.

As an alternative, you could also use MySQL functions to achieve the same goal:

```
NOW()
DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 72 HOUR)
```